# Why is this Rewrite Rule Not Working?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to go from

```
http://domain.site.com/folder/profile.php?name=some_person
```

to the cleaner URL

```
http://sub1.site.com/folder/some_person
```

In my .htaccess I have the relevant section:

```
#Prevent from overriding actual directories and files

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 

# Rewrite user URLs
#   Input:  folder/NAME/
#   Output: profile.php?name=NAME
RewriteRule ^folder/(\w+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1
```

However when I go to

```
http://sub1.site.com/folder/fred
```

for instance (where fred is a valid user), I get 404 page not found error

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Can you edit server config? If yes -- enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLoglevel 9`) and check rewrite log for details. 2) Try replacing `w+` by `[a-zA-Z\_]` (add other acceptable characters if required)

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(\w+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo...thats what i have and i still get the error

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you didn't mention the domain name in the result, your current domain and the result domain are different, I guess it's a mis-typo but if you think it's not then please try the following rule.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1.site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder
RewriteRule ^/folder/(\w+)/?$ http://domain.site.com/folder/profile.php?name=$1 [QSA]
```

Note:
If you think domain is same, then just remove the domain from the rule.

You can validate your rewrite-rule in this link: 
http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/